# Transfer learning with pretrained model by tf.GradientTape can't converge

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0, transfer-learning

I would like to perform transfer learning with pretrained model of keras

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

base_model = keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=(96, 96, 3), include_top=False, pooling='avg')
x = base_model.outputs[0]
outputs = layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)(x)

model = keras.Model(inputs=base_model.inputs, outputs=outputs)
```

Training with keras compile/fit functions can converge

```
model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(), metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train_data, epochs=1)
```

The results are: loss: 0.4402 - accuracy: 0.8548

I wanna train with tf.GradientTape, but it can't converge

```
optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam()
train_loss = keras.metrics.Mean()
train_acc = keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()
def train_step(data, labels):    
    with tf.GradientTape() as gt:
        pred = model(data)
        loss = keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()(labels, pred)

    grads = gt.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)

    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))

    train_loss(loss)
    train_acc(labels, pred)

for xs, ys in train_data:
    train_step(xs, ys)

print('train_loss = {:.3f}, train_acc = {:.3f}'.format(train_loss.result(), train_acc.result()))
```

But the results are: train_loss = 7.576, train_acc = 0.101

If I only train the last layer by setting

```
base_model.trainable = False
```

It converges and the results are: train_loss = 0.525, train_acc = 0.823

What's the problem with the codes? How should I modify it? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried lowering the learning rate to see if it converges then?

Comment: @StatisticDean, I tried lr=0.0001 (default is 0.001), it became train_loss = 0.377, train_acc = 0.874, it did converge, but why? The settings should be as same as Keras. Is there any magic inside keras compile/fit functions? How should I achieve the results as Keras does with the same settings if I wanna write my own training codes? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try RELU as activation function. It may be Vanishing Gradient issue which occurs if you use activation function other than RELU.

Comment: So how should I modify my codes? Replace tf.nn.softmax with tf.nn.relu ? But the same model can be trained by keras fit

Comment: well need to check, i used in different way without tensorflow classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 6, init = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim = 11, kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001)))

Answer (score 1):

Following my comment, the reason why it didn't converge is because you picked a learning rate that was too big. This causes the weight to change too much and the loss to explode. When setting `base_model.trainable` to False, most of the weight in the networks were fixed and the learning rate was a good fit for your last layers. Here's a picture : 
[image]

As a general rule, your learning rate should always be chosen for each experiments.

Edit : Following Wilson's comment, I'm not sure this is the reason you have different results but this could be it :

When you specify your loss, your loss is computed on each element of the batch, then to get the loss of the batch, you can take the sum or the mean of the losses, depending on which one you chose, you get a different magnitude. For example, if your batch size is 64, summing the loss will yield you a 64 times bigger loss which will yield 64 times bigger gradient, so choosing sum over mean with a batch size 64 is like picking a 64 times bigger learning rate. 
So maybe the reason you have different results is that by default a `keras.losses` wrapped in a `model.compile` has a different reduction method. In the same vein, if the loss is reduced by a sum method, the magnitude of the loss depends on the batch size, if you have twice the batch size, you get (on average) twice the loss, and twice the gradient and so it's like doubling the learning rate.

My advice is to check the reduction method used by the loss to be sure it's the same in both case, and if it's sum, to check that the batch size is the same. I would advise to use mean reduction in general since it's not influenced by batch size.

Comment: Thanks for comment. But why does it converge by keras compile/fit functions with the same settings?

Comment: I set the learning rate 0.01 in Keras, much larger than the one used in TF.But it still works not so bad. epoch1: loss: 2.1312 - accuracy: 0.2726, epoch2: loss: 1.5062 - accuracy: 0.4551, epoch3:  loss: 1.1453 - accuracy: 0.5884. But this lr will fail in TF, accuracy=0.1 all the time. Because I will usually write my own training loop for specific purpose, I just want to know why and how to achieve expected results as Keras does. Thanks

Comment: @Wilson I edited the answer to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but It might be a bug in TF2.0-beta1. I haved asked the questions on TF git issue and they reproduce the issue as well and label it as a bug. The link is https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31184,  hope it's helpful

Comment: Thanks for sharing that information. I'm glad you found the reason why you had different results. Still, using the right learning rate remains essential in a good training !

Comment: Yeah! Exactly! Learning rate is really crucial for deep learning. Really appreciate your help, thanks